# Find Grand Total In Array

Tags: c++

I want to find the Grand Total by finding from the unit*price, but it gets 0.00, although it should be 12,640.00 so does anybody know how I can do this?

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *in;

    char id[20][15];  // 20 persons   
    char des[20][15];
    int unit[30];
    float price[30];
    float sum = 0.0, total = 0.0;
    int i=0, j;

    in = fopen("price.txt", "r") ;
    if ( in == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Could not open file test.c" ) ;
        return 1;
    }

    while(!feof(in))
    {
        fscanf(in, "%s %s %d %f", &id[i], &des[i], &unit[i], &price[i]);
        i++;
    }

    printf("No. ID Descripton Price/Unit Unit Total Amount\n");
    for(j=0; j < i ;j++)
       printf("%d. %s %s %d %0.2f %0.2f \n",j, id[j], des[j], unit[j], price[j], unit[j]*price[j]);
    sum = unit[j]*price[j];
    total += sum;
    printf("Grand Total %0.2f",total);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: Only the `printf` statement is in the body of the `for` loop. The statements that update `sum` and `total` are not, and only run once. You already know how to use braces.

Comment: Clue: What do *you* think is the 'body' of your `for(j...)` loop?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate

Comment: Another victim of moving from Python to C.... Neither language is undisputably better than the other, but this change is deadly.

Comment: Since you have no braces (`{}`) on your loop, only the *first* statement following it is actually *in* the loop. Indentation is *not* significant in C++ (unlike Python).

Comment: `FILE *in;` - personally I stop right there. If this is supposed to be C++, then why are we using C style file I/O?

Comment: Please change the tag from C++ to C. There is ZERO C++ code in here.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are a beginner. Well, the error here is that your `for` loop never actually calculates the `sum`
By default, the `for` loop only reads the line below it, unless there is any code enclosed curly braces{} spanning multiple lines.

```
for(j=0; j < i ;j++)
{    
    printf("%d. %s %s %d %0.2f %0.2f \n",j, id[j], des[j], unit[j], 
    price[j], 
    unit[j]*price[j]);
    sum = unit[j]*price[j];
    total += sum;
}
```

Also, just an advice, please try to indent your code better. It will help you in the future :)

Best.